# What does the symbol ! mean in WebStorm's git integration

Tags: git, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I found a symbol `!` between HEAD and REMOTE BRANCH shown as below link. What does it mean?

[image: a symbol ! between HEAD and REMOTE BRANCH]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in the middle of a merge or rebase that could not be completed because it encountered a conflict. The exclamation mark tells you there is a conflict. Go to the "Local Changes" tab, right click on the red file and pick "Resolve Conflicts". Resolve the conflict (i.e. either accept your version or the other version or manually solve the conflicts by editing the code) before you can continue.